# AudioKit: How can I sync an AKOperationGenerator to the frequency of an other Oscillator (oscillator-sync)?

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit, akoperationgenerator, akoperation

I am new to AudioKit. I want to build a Synth with two Oscillators where one is synced by the other, means every wavelength of OSC1 (every second zero-crossing) the OSC2 is restarted (phase set to 0). Is this possible with AKOperation oscillators? thnx!

Edit: Maybe my explanation was very bad. [Wikipedia is better](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscillator_sync): "One oscillator will restart the period of another oscillator, so that they will have the same base frequency. This can produce a musical sound, rich with harmonics. The timbre can be altered on the synched oscillator by varying its frequency input. A synched oscillator that resets the other oscillator(s) is called the master, and any synched oscillator that is reset by another oscillator is called a slave."

And here is some nice sounding visualization [on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3EWT5c7BjM).

[Another Link with image](https://www.keithmcmillen.com/blog/simple-synthesis-part-7-oscillator-sync/) and [some maths](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/30114/what-harmonic-spectrum-is-produced-by-oscillator-sync).

EDIT 2: I have a strong feeling that this needs some DSP code. I thought about triggering stop()-and-start() with phase set to 0 by an Metronome running with the master osc frequency - but this does not sound like a good performing solution.
any thoughts/help is very appreciated!

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're asking and I just wanted to let you know that I'm not just ignoring this question. I just don't see what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thnx  Aurelius - I edited my question, trying to be more specific.

Comment: What have you tried so far; show some code. Easiest is to start within the audiokit playgrounds.

Comment: I have a strong feeling that this needs some DSP code. I thought about stop()-and-start() with phase set to 0 - but this does not sound realistic. I am no-good diving down into C-level, thats why I asked the pro's. But I will constantly think and try and when I come up with code, I will post it here. any thoughts/help is very appreciated!